Conditional If Statements for data format
I would like to skip an iteration of code if, the data in a cell does not match a string - number - number format. For example, the desired format is Apple-34-56. If the array that I defined has a format such as Apple-Grape-23, or any other variation contrary to the desired format, it should skip to the next iteration.
function populateData (sheet1, sheet2) {

    var dataRange = sheet1.getRange("A:A").getValues();

    for (var i = 0; dataRange.length; i++) {

        if (dataRange !== string-number-number) {
            continue;
        }
    }
}

Is this the proper way to set up the condition?

Use a regular expression test. /^\w+-\d+-\d+$/

You have to index datarange: dataRange[i].

What you are asking for is a regular expression to match your desired constraints.
I.e. if you meant "(any-length word)-(any-length number)-(any-length number)" your if statement would become:
if (! dataRange[i].match(/^\w+-\d+-\d+$/)) {...};
// (Notice the `[i]` I guess you missed )

That being said, you can even avoid the continue statement an make which are your targeted inputs even more clear:
const re_fmt = /^\w+-\d+-\d+$/;

function populateData (sheet1, sheet2) {

    var dataRange = sheet1.getRange("A:A").getValues();

    for (
        let i = 0;
        i < dataRange.length;
        i++
    ) if (
        dataRange[i].match(re_fmt)
    ) {

        /* Your code... */

    }
}


A quick easy solution:
function populateData(sheet1, sheet2) {
    var dataRange = sheet1.getRange("A:A").getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < dataRange.length; i++) {
        var cellValue = dataRange[i][0]; // Accessing the value of the cell

        // Splitting the cell value into parts using "-"
        var parts = cellValue.split("-");

        // Checking if the cell value has the desired format: string-number-number
        if (parts.length === 3 && !isNaN(parts[1]) && !isNaN(parts[2])) {
            // Proceed
        } else {
            // Skip this iteration if the format doesn't match
            continue;
        }
    }
}


You can use a lambda to do your array filtering, for example
dataRange.filter(i => i.match(/^\w+-\d+-\d+$/))  // only include matching elements
         .forEach(x => {
             console.log(x);
             // process the array element how you want
          });

(using Barmar's regular expression test /^\w+-\d+-\d+$/ — thanks)
